# Tracking server invasion

Tags: linux, security

I manage a private GNU/Linux server, that only I (should) have access. Over the last few months, it got invaded a few times, always by the same person (he/she runs the same application every time). This person manages to create a root account. I've changed passwords to very strong ones and deleted the created accounts, but they keep getting back in. The problem is I don't know where from.

**My question is:** what are the first steps that I should do to find where my vulnerability is?

Some general comments about my setup:

- Debian 8.6
- Main applications running in the server: apache, dovecot, exim, mysql and owncloud.
- I have fail2ban running.
- I have a script in my `.bashrc` (for my user and for root account) that warns me by email when someones opens a terminal with these accounts. It never gets triggered by the invader.
- The output of the `last` command shows they were using a `tty1` session (whereas when I'm logged it shows `pts/0`). Also in the `last` command, in the column that should say where the access is coming from, their entry is empty.

Comment: Are you formatting and doing a clean install after the compromise?  What commands are being run?  The first step is probably to crank up the logging, and have your logs sent to an external host.

Comment: Is this a VM, and is remote console access enabled? Could `tty1` be your remote console?